# 'Cropping' an SVG, client-side

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, svg

I'm working on a purely client-side SVG editor, and I have a special need:

I need to crop out a rectangular region from the SVG - in this case, the bounding box of an element - and draw it onto a Canvas, using something like `drawImage`.

Is this possible at all?

I've tried using [canvg](http://canvg.googlecode.com/)'s `drawSVG`, which aims to be analogous to `drawImage`, only to discover that it can't crop the input image.

Comment: By _crop out_, do you mean you wish to apply a [mask](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/masking.html) to your SVG?

Comment: @halfer That seems to be close. How would I go forward from that?

Comment: Well, if you're using JS, you need to reform your document so that it contains this new element. I've never used it, but I suspect the thing I linked to is a _container_ for the elements you want to clip. Are you familiar with XML handling (insert new element, move existing elements into child of new element etc.)? As usual, experimentation on a dev machine is needed here `:-)`

Comment: Ah, just spotted from your link - take a look at the docs for `viewport`.